# Reversing the flow of jobs in a workflow

Tags: github, terraform, github-actions

I'm working on some terraform logic and using github workflows to deploy multiple components in a sequential manner like job2(alb) depending on the completion of job1(creation of VPC). This works fine during the apply phase. However if I were to delete the infra using terraform destroy the sequence of jobs fails as job1 can't be successfull without job1.

Is there a way to enable the execution of the workflow in the bottom-up approach based on input?

I know that we can leverage terraform to deploy these components and handle the dependencies at terraform level. This is an example of a use case I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the flow of jobs by using the keyword “needs”. Read the docs here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds

Comment: needs works to define the sequential order. However I defined the flow in sequence using needs for the creation of infrastructure, but while deleting the infra, i want the same steps to be processed in the reverse order.